# htaccess point request to sub-directory if file doesn't exists and does under the subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm having a really hard time with trying to get this to work so I have a sub-directory `example.com/projects` with a directory under that called `test` and I'd like it if someone typed `example.com/test` it would show the file from `example.com/projects/test` but if the file does not exist I would like it to post a 404 error.

Additionally if possible I would like any time `example.com/projects/test` was typed it would redirect to `example.com/test` instead but if someone goes to just `projects/` I want them to be able to stay there.

I have tried the following .htaccess files so far

---

This works almost perfectly passing through the files unless the file doesn't exist in which it throws a 500 Internal Server Error

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ projects/$1 [PT]
```

I thought something like this might work to only pass through if the file existed under projects but doesn't work at all:

```
RewriteCond projects/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond projects/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ projects/$1 [PT]
```

---

For the second part pointing anything that goes to `/projects/test` to strip `/projects` I tried this (placed before the code above)

```
RedirectMatch ^/projects/(.+)$ /$1
```

Only to find a redirect loop. How can i prevent this?

---

My current .htaccess file for reference:

```
ErrorDocument 404     /404.html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example2\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example2\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/example3\.org" [R=301,L]

#RedirectMatch ^/projects/(.+)$ /$1
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ projects/$1 [PT]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules in your root .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /projects/(\S+)\sH [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=302,NE]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/projects/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/projects/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ projects/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me. with all of it running (in the root .htaccess) everything redirects to the home directory and nothing works anymore. commenting out the first part seems to work for redirecting for some files (might be cached) but gives 404 errors for things that should be there. I used a 302 redirect instead of the 301 you suggested however not that it should of affected anything other than my ability to undo later.

Comment: I tried a few of them, 2 urls worked probably because I tried them with another rewrite rule but the url i tried (which is also a directory under /projects) gave a 404 error (without the first set of rewrite conditions you said) and just gave a normal 404 page. with the `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /projects/(\S*)\sH [NC]` bit everything i pointed to even /asdfas redirected right to example.com just showing the homepage. and I added the .htaccess in the original question as it is right now

Comment: Oh, I see what happened. yes it kinda works but you have to declare the file which I'd rather not do. so i have `example.com/projects/test/index.html` which works if i type it just like that but if i just type `example.com/projects/test/` it 404's. can it be done the other way?

Comment: Yes that works perfectly, is there a simple way to add if someone goes to /projects/test/ it redirect to just /test/ for SEO friendliness?

Comment: okay that worked perfectly but I found a small problem with the second half. if the url is just / it shouldn't redirect to /projects/ i remember something about this along the lines of (.+)$ ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112838/discussion-between-anubhava-and-zfb).